# Compute differece between timestamp values in secoonds

Tags: time

I want to calculate the frame per second value by computing the number of images captured in 1 second. For this purpose, I want to use the Timestamps given by the camera.

I want to subtract the current Timestamp value from the initial Timestamp value ***to calculate the number of seconds elapsed***.

An example of my Timestamp values looks like **788343977**.

**QUESTIONS:** How can I subtract the timestamps values to calculate the time elapsed in seconds?

Comment: You need to figure out what unit your timestamp 788343977 is in. Is it in units of miliseconds ? 100th of a second ? A frame number ?

Comment: What is your timestamp ? seconds ? milliseconds ?

Comment: That is the main problem that I don't know the units. The camera manufacturer has not written anything about it (btw its NET camera).

Comment: What is the length of your video ? You can guess the unit of your timestamp if it corresponds to a given event on the camera.

Comment: I am capturing the live images. I got the value "788343977" by running the live image capturing program only for few seconds 3-5 secs.

Comment: And what is your initial timestamp ?

Comment: I again started the program and ran for 9 seconds...my current timestamp is 1999854657. I think the timestamp is dependent on the current system timings and does not start from zero as mentioned in several weblinks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you get the timestamp `t1 = 788343977` by running 3 seconds and you get the timestamp `t2 = 1999854657` when running 9 seconds, a **second** is equivalent to almost (approximation errors) `s = (t2-t1)/6 = 201918446`. So your might be dealing with **nanoseconds**.

Try this out :

```
def t_elapsed(t, t_init):
    if t < t_init :
        raise ValueError("Given timestamp smaller than initial one")
    else:
        return (t-t_init)/float(1e9)
```